# Image not Going into Divider?

Tags: html

Im working on a website, and Im trying to put a navigation bar in the navigation divider I made, however when I put the image in, it doesnt go into the divider, even though its between the  tags. 
Heres what it looks like: 
[image]

Heres My code:

CSS:

```
body{background-color:#030303}
#wrapper {width:800px;
margin:0 auto;
}
#header {background-color:yellow;
text-align:center; 
height:50px;
}
#footer{clear:both; 
background-color:yellow ;
text-allign:center;
}
#logo {float:left;
width: 139px;
background-color: black;
text-align: left;
height:70px;}

#navigation {width: 800px;
background-color:#EDEDED;
height:50px;
}
#sidebar {float:left;padding:20px; background-color:green;text-align:right;width:100px;height:460px;}
#content {float:right;width: 620px;
padding:20px; background-color:gray;
text-align:left; height:500px;
border-color:#0017FF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <title>Website</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div  id="header">
This is my header.
</div>
<div id="logo">
<br/>
<img src="images/SubZer0-logo-and-name.png" width="140" height="50" align="left"></div>
<div  id="navigation">
<img src="images/subzero-banner-new.png" width="750" height="45" align="top">
</div>

<div  id="content">
This is my content box.
</div>
<div  id="sidebar">
This is my sidebar.
</div>
<div  id="footer">
This is my footer.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How Do I fix this? 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried CSS float? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: @Mooseman yeah i tried it, but when i do that, the navigation bar(Light Gray) moves down and the logo divider disappears (the one with the logo in top left).

Comment: Also define all `margin` and `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, I fixed it... Turns out the image was too big for the container.. I dont understand why though, Since the Containter was 800x50 and the image was 750x45, but it works now and thats what matters.

Comment: I noticed a few things in your code that will give you a bunch of problems. One of the biggest issues was that the wrapper had a defined width, so if you wanna change the size of something in it then it won't resize with that element. Might I recommend tables? I did everything for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/sAQbt/ only thing that didn't work 100% was the logo, because it got off set by a bit at the top (not too hard to fix). This will allow you change size of any of the items without having to change a 1000 other things.

Comment: @theSuburbanGangster I already finished the project, however thanks so much for this code, it will be a great reference in the future!